# copy tcpdump command output to a file in android applicaiton

Tags: java, android, tcpdump

I am relatively new to Android. I need to send the tcpdump output to a file. I tried using

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tcpdump -w /sdcard/capture.txt"); and
>   Process proc = new ProcessBuilder().command("tcpdump", "-w", "/sdcard /capture.txt").start();

Whereas these commands seem to be working fine from the command line, it seems to be causing a problem in the code using the above mentioned functions.

Any suggestion would be of great help. 
-Thanks!